# не срабатывает роутинг (node.js, express, mongo)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

При переходе на localhost:5000/api/users должна срабатывать функция getUsers и выводить массив, просто для проверки того, что работает контроллер, но я получаю 404.

```
------app.js-----------

const express = require('express');
const config = require('config');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const app = express();
const router = require('../routes/index')

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/api', router);

const PORT = config.get('port') || 5000;

function exit() {

}
async function start() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(config.get('mongoUri'), {
            autoIndex: true,
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        });
        app.listen(PORT, () => {console.log(`мы тут на ${PORT} порту запустились`)});
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Server error', e.message);
      process.exit(1);
    }
}
start();
```

```
----  /routes/index.js

const Router = require('express').Router;
const router = new Router();

const userController = require('../controllers/user-controller');



router.post('/registration', userController.registration);
router.post('/login', userController.login);
router.post('/logout', userController.logout);
router.post('/activate/:link', userController.activation);
router.post('/refresh', userController.refresh);
router.post('/users', userController.getUsers);

module.exports = router
```

```
----   /controllers/user-controller.js


class UserController {

    async registration(req, res, next) {
        try {

        } catch (e) {
            
        }
        
    }

    async login(req, res, next) {
        try {

        } catch (e) {

        }

    }

    async logout(req, res, next) {
        try {

        } catch (e) {

        }

    }

    async activation(req, res, next) {
        try {

        } catch (e) {

        }

    }
    async refresh(req, res, next) {
        try {

        } catch (e) {

        }

    }

    async getUsers(req, res, next) {
        try {
            res.json([123,456]);
        } catch (e) {

        }

    }


}

module.exports = new UserController();
```

Comment: Кому должна? У вас прямым текстом написано `app.use('/api', router)`, т.е. запрос должен быть `localhost:5000/api/users`

Comment: @Alexey Ten , прошу прощения. все верно, запрос должен быть такой localhost:5000/api/users, но функция все равно не отрабатывает.

Comment: Слово «переход» обычно подразумевает GET-запрос. У вас роутер обрабатывает только POST-запросы. Если это не так, то запрос и ответ в студию.

Comment: @Alexey Ten, заменил на router.get('/users', userController.getUsers); и все работает. Делал по уроку, там в примере везде POST-запросы.